# What does AccessibilityManager.interrupt() exactly do?

Tags: android, accessibility-api

As it often happens in Android Developer "Documentation", the description of this function is ridiculously vague:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.html#interrupt()

> Requests feedback interruption from all accessibility services.

Does anybody know exactly what it does, what are its effects and how long it will last? For example, with TalkBack and Explore On Touch enabled, will this interrupt the current utterance that is being spoken, or will it shut down the service for the rest of the activity lifecycle?

Also, what does "request" mean? Does it mean that the request might not be satisfied? If so, in which cases, and how do you check whether it was succesful?

Comment: Calm down, mate. A typical scenario where `interrupt()` is used is, for example, when a TTS service is being executed but the user touch the screen to explore, the `interrupt()` would determine whether the TTS service should stop or pause until the touch event is finished i.e. the user is not touching the screen anymore.

Comment: I don't remember if you are the same person who wrote the comment "eh, just code an example and find out for yourselve [sic]" which has been deleted. If you're not, then that may explain to you why my previous comment, which I will now delete.